# How to report progress via HTTP when converting a file and sending it in the same request?

Tags: angular, spring, http, websocket, server-sent-events

using Angular and Spring: I have a POST endpoint that creates a zip file from several other files and sends this zip file back to the client afterwards. The zip file can be very large, in rare instances up to 20GB.
By default the user can see the progress only after the zip file conversion has finished and the file download is running.
Since the conversion can take several minutes I decided to provide progress updates to the frontend/user. Right now theses progress updates are implemented using Websockets/STOMP.

I would say the approach is OK, but a downside is that I have to manage two connections to correctly update the UI in the frontend (e.g. fail when either HTTP request fails or websocket times out).

I have read about server-sent-events and figured potentially they can also be used for this purpose, but I could not find much about my exact use case (conversion with progress + file download afterwards) online.

Is there any way to provide the progress reporting + file download within the same request?

Comment: 1) initiate process with HTTP request, DO NOT hold it open, it already did its purpose 2) listen for process like you do 3) when process finishes (progress says its done), make another httpcall to get the result.

Comment: if it is a big file you have to change spring http request to MULTIPART_FORM then process will be returned in http response subscibe it and update progress bar. here is a nice blog :-https://javaninja.io/angular-9-spring-boot-rest-api-file-upload-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Currently if the request finishes or gets aborted, the temp file gets deleted. This ensures  that users can't use up a lot of disk space by spamming requests. Of course it would be solvable using rate limiting and a cleaning Thread for the Temp files, but it would make additional implementation effort. I am generally interested whether it is possible to report the progress within the same HTTP request.

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks, I followed your approach in the end.
The thing that made me finally switch the approach was that i was fetching the resulting file using the browsers fetch API, which loaded the entire file into the RAM before performing the actual download (from within the browsers memory). 
In step 3) that you mentioned I download the file now from a public endpoint using a HTML <a> Element, which streams the File to Disk.

For anyone else having this problem, another approach might be using this library: https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js?

Comment: StreamSaver creates `<a>` on the fly in most cases.